Disabling and Enabling a Method from a Different Script
I've created a new gameObject that follows the same rotation as my playerObject and I've attached two scripts to that object, one to stop the rotation within a certain range above the player and one for below the player.
public GameObject player;

    public float turnSpeed = 6f;

    public bool lookAtMouseEnabled;
    float minUpRotation = 350f;
    float maxUpRotation = 10f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (lookAtMouseEnabled)
        {
            player.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().Lookatmouse();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Rotate();

        float yRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        if (yRotation >= minUpRotation || yRotation <= maxUpRotation)
        {
            lookAtMouseEnabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lookAtMouseEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    public void Rotate()
    {
        Plane playerplane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (playerplane.Raycast(ray, out float hitdist))
        {
            Vector3 targetpoint = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
            Quaternion targetrotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetpoint - transform.position);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetrotation, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

The other script is the same but between 170f and 190f.
The problem is I can see the lookAtMouseEnabled bool being checked in the right areas, but when the gameObject rotates out of the min and max ranges the playerObject rotation is still stuck in one area?

Just from glancing over the code, it strikes me as odd that lookAtMouseEnabled does not seem to be used anywhere besides Start.

The other script is the same but between 170f and 190f. ... in general use the same script and rather expose these two fields to the Inspector so you can reuse the same code instead of re-implementing two classes just because they use two different values ;)

@Sebastián thank you, I meant to call it in Update

@derHugo I used to have combined logic in which it looked like this if ((yRotation >= minUpRotation && yRotation <= maxUpRotation) || (yRotation >= minDownRotation && yRotation <= maxDownRotation)) but I understand now that minUpRotation and maxUpRotation will always overlap 170f and 190f.
